# Working with UTF-8 in Python

Tags: python, utf-8, arabic

As it is summer now, I decided to learn a new language and Python was my choice. Really, what I would like to learn is how to manipulate Arabic text using Python. Now, I have found many many resources on using Python, which are really great. However, when I apply what I learned on Arabic strings, I get numbers and letters combined together.

Take for example this for English:

```
>>> ebook = 'The American English Dictionary'
>>> ebook[2]
'e'
```

Now, for Arabic:

```
>>> abook = 'القاموس العربي'
>>> abook[2]
'\xde'                  #the correct output should be 'ق'
```

However, using `print` works fine, as in:

```
>>> print abook[2]
ق
```

What do I need to modify to get Python to always recognize Arabic letters?

Comment: Use Python 3 or Unicode literals: `u"القاموس العربي"`

Comment: I would really recommend taking a look at this talk at Pycon 2012 [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How do I stop the pain?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc&feature=results_video&playnext=1&list=PL64CA5D679C54E4E9). After watching it you should feel much more comfortable with unicode. And if you are working with arabic you will need it.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply.  I applied the Unicode literal and I got: >>> tmp = u"القاموس العربي"
>>> tmp
u'\xc7\xe1\xde\xc7\xe3\xe6\xd3 \xc7\xe1\xda\xd1\xc8\xed'
>>> print tmp
ÇáÞÇãæÓ ÇáÚÑÈí

Comment: Often, your I/O device doesn't support Unicode -- for example, cmd.exe on Windows. In those cases Python is doing fine, you just can't see it.

Comment: If that were the case, then: >>> print abook[2]
ق         wouldn't print out the properly.  But it does.  Meaning if I use 'print' before the variable, it will return the correct Unicode letter.  If I omit 'print' it will print out '\xde'

Comment: @FavnHghksd: the difference between `ق` and `'\xd9\x82'` in the output is the difference between `print 'ق'` and `print repr('ق')`. By default ([`sys.displayhook`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook)), the REPL shows you `repr` of the object (an unambiguous representation aimed at `o == eval(repr(o))`). `print 'ق'` produces a more human-readable (but possibly ambiguous) representation.

Answer (score 4):

Use Unicode explicitly:

```
>>> s = u'القاموس العربي'
>>> s
u'\u0627\u0644\u0642\u0627\u0645\u0648\u0633 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u0628\u064a'
>>> print s
القاموس العربي

>>> print s[2]
ق
```

Or even character by character:

```
>>> for i, c in enumerate(s):
...     print i,c
... 
0 ا
1 ل
2 ق
3 ا
4 م
5 و
6 س
7  
8 ا
9 ل
10 ع
11 ر
12 ب
13 ي
14
```

I recommend the [Python Unicode page](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) which is short, practical and useful.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I tried your first set of code but I did not get the same results as you: >>> s = u'القاموس العربي'
>>> s
u'\xc7\xe1\xde\xc7\xe3\xe6\xd3 \xc7\xe1\xda\xd1\xc8\xed'
>>> print s
ÇáÞÇãæÓ ÇáÚÑÈí
>>> print s[2]
Þ

Comment: That is most likely a problem with the encoding of the shell.

Comment: I am using Windows XP Professional and the Python GUI IDLE shell

Answer (score 3):

Use python 3.x: strings are now unicode- see [python 3 what is new](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit)

```
>>> abook = 'القاموس العربي'
>>> abook[0]
'ا'
>>> abook[4]
'م'
```

Comment: "Use Python 3" is not an answer.

Comment: I was going to use python 3 but many people have said that it is not fully compatible (even many of the sites I have been using to learn about python have stated to avoid downloading the newest version).

Comment: @FavnHghksd you will find that most major third-party libraries are compatible by now - enough that unless you have a particular one you're holding out on, Py3 will serve you better than Py2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the input:

```
>>> abook[2]
```

to produce the following output:

```
'ق'
```

it'll never happen. The interactive shell prints `repr(abook[2])`, which will always use escape sequences for arabic characters. I don't know the exact rules, but I'm guessing that most characters outside the ASCII universe will be escaped. To make it work as advertised, you use the `u` prefix, but it will still output an escape sequence (albeit the correct one, this time):

```
>>> abook = u'القاموس العربي'
>>> abook[2]
u'\u0642'
```

The reason you get `'\xde'` is that without the `u` prefix, abook holds the UTF-8 encoding of the phrase. My output differs from yours (possibly because the code points were altered through copy-pasting; I'm not sure), but the principle still holds:

```
>>> abook = 'القاموس العربي'
>>> ' '.join( hex(ord(c))[-2:] for c in abook )
'd8 a7 d9 84 d9 82 d8 a7 d9 85 d9 88 d8 b3 20 d8 a7 d9 84 d8 b9 d8 b1 d8 a8 d9 8a'
>>> abook[2]
'\xd9'
```

You can confirm this as follows:

```
>>> abook = 'القاموس العربي'
>>> unicode(abook, 'utf-8')[2]
u'\u0642'
>>> print unicode(abook, 'utf-8')[2]
ق
```

Comment: Hi Marcelo, thank you for replying.  I tried your first statement, but I do not get the same result as you though.  Here is what I got: >>> abook = u'القاموس العربي'
>>> abook[2]
u'\xde'

Comment: @FavnHghksd: I addressed that in my answer. "My output differs from yours…". I can't offer any more insight than I already have, I'm afraid.

Comment: I got this exception "TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported" help please

Comment: @WilliamKinaan: Raise a separate question and post details of your scenario. (You can link back to this answer if you think it'll offer useful context.)

Answer (score 0):

Going by the result in the comments on the question, this looks like `repr` is causing a [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) issue - that is, it is getting confused about encodings and using the wrong one. `print` will try to use the encoding it thinks your STDOUT uses, and print the resultant bytes directly - repr tries to print an ASCII-safe representation, although seems to be failing badly in this situation.

The good news is - this is an issue with `repr`, not with Python's Unicode handling. As long as the roundtrip: `s.encode('utf8').decode('utf8') == s` works, you're fine. `print` the value  when you want to inspect it, don't just mention it at the interative terminal, and use Unicode strings everywhere (using Py3 will help massively with this, or at minimum do:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from io import open
```

), keep track of encodings, and your program will work even if `repr` happens to do something bizarre.

Also note that your question is *not* about UTF8 in any way - its about Unicode, which is a different (though related) concept. If the resources you've been reading haven't enforced this difference, get better resources - a misunderstanding of these concepts will lead you to a lot of pain.