# Working with Non-UTF-8 codes in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first question in StackOverflow. I've been trying to print() an Arabic string. my code is:

```
s = '''
<b>سُوۡرَةُ الفَاتِحَة</b><br>بِسۡمِ اللهِ الرَّحۡمٰنِ الرَّحِيۡمِ <br></span></font></div><div dir="RTL" align="right"><font id="fon1" class="Arabic-IndoPak" size="5.2" color="#000000"><span id="mspan1">اَلۡحَمۡدُ لِلّٰهِ رَبِّ الۡعٰلَمِيۡنَۙ‏ ﴿﻿۱﻿﴾ &nbsp;</span></font><font id="SubTotFont1" size="0"></font><font id="fon2" class="Arabic-IndoPak" size="5.2" color="#000000"><span id="mspan2">الرَّحۡمٰنِ الرَّحِيۡمِۙ‏ ﴿﻿۲﻿﴾ &nbsp;</span></font><font id="SubTotFont2" size="0"></font><font id="fon3" class="Arabic-IndoPak" size="5.2" color="#000000"><span id="mspan3">مٰلِكِ يَوۡمِ الدِّيۡنِؕ‏ ﴿﻿۳﻿﴾ &nbsp;</span></font><font id="SubTotFont3" size="0"></font><font id="fon4" class="Arabic-IndoPak" size="5.2" color="#000000"><span id="mspan4">اِيَّاكَ نَعۡبُدُ  وَاِيَّاكَ نَسۡتَعِيۡنُؕ‏ ﴿﻿۴﻿﴾ &nbsp;</span></font><font id="SubTotFont4" size="0"></font><font id="fon5" class="Arabic-IndoPak" size="5.2" color="#000000"><span id="mspan5">اِهۡدِنَا الصِّرَاطَ  الۡمُسۡتَقِيۡمَۙ‏ ﴿﻿۵﻿﴾ &nbsp;</span></font><font id="SubTotFont5" size="0"></font><font id="fon6" class="Arabic-IndoPak" size="5.2" color="#000000"><span id="mspan6">صِرَاطَ الَّذِيۡنَ اَنۡعَمۡتَ عَلَيۡهِمۡ ۙ‏ ﴿﻿۶﻿﴾ &nbsp;</span></font><font id="SubTotFont6" size="0"></font><font id="fon7" class="Arabic-IndoPak" size="5.2" color="#000000"><span id="mspan7">غَيۡرِ الۡمَغۡضُوۡبِ عَلَيۡهِمۡ وَلَا الضَّآلِّيۡنَ‏ ﴿﻿۷﻿﴾ &nbsp;</span></font><font id="SubTotFont7" size="0"></font>
'''

print(s)
```

but it shows this error:

```
C:\Users\AlT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/AlT/PycharmProjects/RAW/RAW.py
  File "C:/Users/AlT/PycharmProjects/RAW/RAW.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfe' in file C:/Users/AlT/PycharmProjects/RAW/RAW.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone please tell me how to print these Arabic characters?

Comment: It should be working without a problem I ran it here and it worked normally! https://repl.it/IOkk/0
maybe its a windows setup related problem?

Comment: I'm using pycharm. IDK whats wrong in that :(

Comment: try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your python file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with UTF-8 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175976/working-with-utf-8-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

Use :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Hi, I would highly recommend you to check this page about python encoding : 
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Even though in Python3+ utf8 encoding declaration is not needed since utf-8 is the new default source file !
(see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/)